# For loop in velocity template

Tags: for-loop, velocity

I would like to use the for loop in velocity template like below -

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){}
```

Any idea how to define in vm?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Range Operator](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#range-operator):

```
#foreach($i in [0..9])
    $i
#end
```

Comment: Note that the start and end are inclusive in Velocity ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to serg's answer, if you want a zero-indexed loop but only have an exclusive end value (and don't want to subtract 1 with `#set`), you can use the builtin `$foreach.index`. If you want to loop `$n` times:

```
#foreach($unused in [1..$n])
    zero indexed: $foreach.index
#end
```

here, `$unused` is unused, and we instead use `$foreach.index` for our index, which starts at 0.

Let's say `$n` is 3.

We start the range at 1 as it's inclusive, and so it will loop with `$unused` being [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], whereas `$foreach.index` will be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

See [the user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#foreach-loop) for more.